# Why are semileptonic decays of the $\Lambda$ baryon so suppressed?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, weak-interaction, baryons

Looking at the [Particle Data Group tables](http://pdglivetest.lbl.gov/Particle.action?init=0&node=S018&home=BXXX020) of the $\Lambda$ baryon, I find that the rate of the hadronic decay $\Lambda \to p \pi^-$ is 64% while the semileptonic decay $\Lambda \to p e^-\nu_e$ has the rate of $8 \times 10^{-4}$.

I cannot explain what is the reason for such large suppression of the semileptonic decay of the $\Lambda$.
Both $\Lambda \to p \pi^-$ and $\Lambda \to p e^-\nu_e$ decays originate from the same Feynman diagram, $s \to u W^-$ at the quark level, with $W^-$ going either to $\overline{u}d$ or $e^-\nu_e$. So, I would expect the factor 3 difference between these two diagrams, due to the color factor; which could then be diminished by the smaller phase-space in the hadronic decay compared to the semileptonic one. However, the actual difference in rate of $\Lambda \to p \pi^-$ and $\Lambda \to p e^-\nu_e$ is factor 800, so my estimation is wrong.

The assumption that a three-body decay would somehow be more suppressed than a two-body decay, also does not work, as the charged kaon, $K^-$, [decays](http://pdglivetest.lbl.gov/Particle.action?init=0&node=S010&home=MXXX020#decays) (via the same Feynman diagrams as the decays discussed above, modulo one spectator quark) to $\pi^0\pi^-$ in about 21% of times, and to $\pi^0 e^-\nu_e$ in about 5% of times (so, factor 4 difference instead of 800). There should be some suppression affecting only baryonic decays but not mesonic... but I do not see where it might come from.

In a [related question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/208460/why-does-virtual-negative-w-boson-decay-mainly-into-antiup-and-down-quarks-durin), a suggestion has been made that semileptonic decays might be affected by the helicity suppression. However, under that assumption, I would expect the $\Lambda \to p \mu^-\nu_\mu$ decay to dominate over $\Lambda \to p e^-\nu_e$ (like in a pion decay), which is not the case.

What am I missing?

(This question is motivated by my [previous question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/557066/why-are-the-lifetimes-of-the-neutral-and-charged-xi-hyperons-so-different#557122) on hyperon lifetimes.)

Comment: The comparison  $\Gamma_e/\Gamma_\mu\approx 5 $ is not too far from the customary 5th power of available momenta, $(163/131)^5\approx 3 $... It's the cheapest dimensional guess for widths that are inversely proportional to the inverse fourth power of $M_W$...

Comment: So far, I'm stumped. They *all* do this, $\Lambda, \Sigma^{\pm}, \Xi, \Omega$. The [standard review](https://www.annualreviews.org/doi/10.1146/annurev.nucl.53.013103.155258)  refers to it as an experimental fact. But BR factors of 800 do not arise from a few wave function peculiarities and extra diagrams... Good question.

Comment: But only hyperons. The charmed baryons or the $\Lambda_b$ have a few % rate of their heavy-quark semileptonic decays. (It would be interesting to look at strangeness-changing decays of $\Xi_c$ or $\Xi_b$ where phase-space is as small as in hyperon decays, but only $\Xi_b^- \to \Lambda_b \pi^-$ has been measured out of them.)

Comment: Yes, $\Lambda_c^+$ has 6% for β-decay... Looks like as the lost quark gets heavier, the situation "normalizes". All this, points, then, to a freak wavefunction  enhancement of the hadronic modes  for the lighter quarks...  still intriguing.

Comment: There is some discussion in https://arxiv.org/abs/1007.3268, but the document is rather messy.

Comment: OK, I checked with *real* experts that it is a murky long-distance / hadronization business, involving P waves, penguin diagrams, etc... cf [Wu & Rosner 1986](https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.33.1367). The takeaway is that it is a recondite "just so" situation, and there is no quick-and-dirty "of course!" explanation... the strong interactions conspire... But your e-print discussion above is unsettling!

Answer (score 2):

The hadronic decay can also go through the exchange of a W.  (The gluon can come from anywhere)

[image]

Apologies for low-quality diagram...

Comment: there are two weak vertices there. But it could explain how for the higher lamdas ( c ) equillibrioum is found. see comment in my "so called" answer.

Comment: There are two weak vertices in the alternative with a W producing $\overline u d$ or $e \nu$.

Comment: If you read my answer, you will see that since W couples to  electromagnetic also, a  higer order quark antiquark pair from virtual photons is much more probable than with weak vertices.

Comment: You still have two weak vertices. There is a change in strangeness so there has to be a W, and that has to have two ends. Adding photons can't alter that.

Comment: I count it as one weak vertex, which exists for both leptonic and hadronic decays in Λ . My argument is that it is electromagnetic ones that create the balance in te quark antiquark pairs in  the hadronic decays..

Comment: I don't see how you can draw the diagram.   Btw the PDG gives the W branching ratio to hadrons as 67%.  (Top of  page 6 in the reference you kindly link to).  This is what you expect from 2 generations * 3 colours of quark modes versus 3 lepton modes, ignoring phase space and the b quark.

Comment: You are correct , so I willdelete my answer/comment, as I misread the table

Comment: The $Ω^−$  has the same dominance of hadronic modes, without extra diagrams, though... An extra diagram and the interferences it enables is hard to parlay to a factor of 800 in the rate, no? –

Comment: ... but nevertheless your extra diagram does figure in [Wu & Rosner 1986](https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.33.1367), along with Penguins, etc... A recondite business...