# Running coupling constants

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model

I am slightly confused about the coupling constants of the fundamental forces and would really appreciate some help in clearing up this confusion.

Some sources(like this one: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Forces/couple.html) seem to convey that $\alpha_W= 10^{-6}$ while some other sources like the text by Griffiths on particle physics suggest that $\alpha_W\sim1/30$.

My guess is that this has something to do with running coupling but I am not really sure. Any reference to how $\alpha_W$ changes with energy would be helpful too.

Comment: Perhaps [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/565409/what-is-the-relative-strength-of-the-weak-force/565520#565520) might reduce your puzzlement. The running of dimensionless gauge couplings is a mere distraction in your question. The differences are definitional and methodological.

Comment: Page 4 of the [PDG](https://pdg.lbl.gov/2019/reviews/rpp2019-rev-standard-model.pdf), the standard go-to reference in particle physics, confirms that the actual running is quite small; from the macroscopic/asymptotic  $1/137 \to 1/133.5$ at the Z mass.

Comment: Thanks @CosmasZachos , I think that answer really helped clear the confusion. 
Just to confirm: The relation $\alpha_W*(sin(\theta_W))^2=\alpha$ is always valid. The low energy(~0.1 GeV) values of $\alpha_W$ and $\alpha$ are 1/30 and 1/137 respectively. As the energy is increased, both of them have a running value(which is small change as per PDG). The 10^-6/10^13 are actually talking about the effective coupling in different energy regimes and not talking about the coupling constants as such. 
Is this correct?

Comment: Also, the linked answer states that "EM cross sections decrease like 1/s, while weak ones increase like s" Could you help me see why?

Comment: Yes, your comment understanding is basically sound. The answer to your 2nd comment is essentially dimensional analysis. In natural units, σ goes like inverse energy squared, so EM which has no significant scale must go like 1/s. By contrast, EW at "lower" energies goes like $G_F^2 \propto 1/M_W^4$ so needs s upstairs for dimensional consistency, very crudely.

Comment: Thanks again @CosmasZachos.
While digging deeper, I found another point of confusion though. I saw a plot which shows $\alpha_W$ decreasing with energy while $\alpha$ increases with energy. How does that reconcile with the fact that $\alpha_W * (sin(\theta_W)^2)=\alpha$?

Comment: You are describing phenomena *above* the EW SSB scale, TeV/4.  The *α* increasing with energy is that of weak hypercharge, U(1), while the decreasing one is the asymptotically free coupling of EW SU(2); at the SSB scale, the two couplings mix together to produce the EM *α* and the weak one. When evolving  couplings with energy, the mixing is taken into consideration, which accounts for the vagueness of the description, which opts fo r conceptual simplicity over messy, indeed devilish, detailed accounting...

Comment: Hi @CosmasZachos, sorry for the late reply. I tried finding for some references to understand better but was unable to find something nice. Could you point me to something that will help me understand this better or maybe explain it in a few more words if possible? Thanks.

Comment: Different question to be asked. I believe you are referring to  Fig 3 of [this](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Grand_unification), describing the flow of the U(1) of hypercharge versus SU(2) above the SSB scale, when EM is unified /mixed with the weak interactions.A book on GUTs would detail it. There is no brisk explanation in a few words.